# Is catching MongoException necessary?

Tags: java, mongodb, exception

Suppose i have the following code:

```
...
this.mongoTemplate.getCollection(sessionId).remove(new BasicDBObject();
...
```

Hovering over *remove*, displays

> Remove documents from a collection.
>
> Parameters: query the deletion criteria using query operators. Omit
>   the query parameter or pass an empty document to delete all documents
>   in the collection. Returns: the result of the operation **Throws:
>   com.mongodb.WriteConcernException** - if the write failed due some other
>   failure specific to the delete command **MongoException** - if the
>   operation failed for some other reason @mongodb.driver.manual
>   tutorial/remove-documents/ Remove Documents

Compiler is not complaining about possible to be thrown exception, so i'm wondering if there's need to catch *MongoException* in these and many other calls of in mongodb java driver

Comment: Exception handling technique is there for a purpose, like define alternative flow in case of exception, don't abruptly throw user to some unknown state etc., whether you need to catch an exception or not depends on how many of these purposes you would like to address.

Comment: yes, but it's just there in documentation, compiler doesn't complain about it.

Comment: Are you sure enclosing method didn't declare throws clause?

Comment: i see that MongoException extends RuntimeException, so i guess i need to remove catch clauses, as this is not checked exception

Comment: yes, i'm sure, otherwise, compiler would shout